# How to return pointers to arrays from functions?

Tags: c, arrays, function-prototypes

I want a function to return a pointer to an array of size 10. What is the prototype for such a function?

I have tried 3 different prototypes and it doesn't work:

```
int(*)[10] returnPtrArray(int (*arr)[10])
{
    return arr;
}
//The return type doesn't seem to work

int(*)[10] returnPtrArray(int[][10]);
int (returnPtrArray(int[][10])(*)[10];
int(*)(returnPtrArray(int[][10])[10];
//none of these prototypes seem to work

//calling
int main()
{
    int a[5][10];
    int (*ptr)[10] = returnPtrArray(&a);
    //How do I make this work?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct definition of the function would be:

```
int (*returnPtrArray(int (*arr)[10]))[10]
{
    return arr;
}
```

Breaking this down: `returnPtrArray` is a function:

```
returnPtrArray()
```

That takes a pointer to an array of 10 `int`:

```
returnPtrArray(int (*arr)[10])
```

And returns a pointer:

```
*returnPtrArray(int (*arr)[10])
```

To an array of size 10:

```
(*returnPtrArray(int (*arr)[10]))[10]
```

Of `int`:

```
int (*returnPtrArray(int (*arr)[10]))[10]
```

And you would call it like this:

```
int a[5][10];
int (*ptr)[10] = returnPtrArray(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this prototype:

```
int (*returnPtrArray(int (*arr)[10]))[10];
```

which is method named returnPtrArray, and takes as a parameter a pointer to an array of 10 integers.

It returns a pointer to an array of 10 integers.

Check it out in the <kbd>[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JPZXiuo0v09tH6J9)</kbd>, where I removed the `&` from the parameter in the method call, since it would be wrong.

---

This answer was based on the more analytic post [Declare a C/C++ function returning pointer to array of integer pointers](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/declare-a-cc-function-returning-pointer-to-array-of-integers/).

Comment: No, it is not wrong. I didn't downvote the answer. Somone else must have.

Comment: Thanks @DarkAtom. I suggest that you accept dbush's answer, because it's far more analytical (after their edit), than mine's!

Comment: I commented on his answer that I will. I upvoted yours too because it is not wrong and does not deserve a -1 (idk who downvoted it).

Answer (score -1):

Pointers don't have knowledge of what they point to, beyond type. If you need to pass an array, you need to pass in a pointer along with the length of the array in a separate parameter (or use a list implementation like `std::vector`).

Comment: You don't *need* to pass the length (it might be defined in a constant somewhere), although it is often a good idea.  And if you aren't in a position to change the type, `vector` might not be an option (no matter how good an idea it is).

Comment: For a function that simply returns the array, you don't need to pass the size since you are not accessing the array so there is no risk of going out of bounds. Also, what you say does not answer my question. Downvoted.

Comment: By the way, you are recommending the use of `std::vector`, but did you see the question is tagged as C, not C++?